# Magento adding reference block for cms widgets

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm trying to add sliders inside my product view page. There are already a couple of presets within the CMS Widgets but none of them are at the location I want.

First I went into page.xml and added:

```
        <block type="core/text_list" name="testproduct" as="test_product" translate="label">
            <label>TEST PRODUCT</label>
        </block>
```

This added an additional block reference in the cms widget page.

Then in my view.phtml I added:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('test_product');
```

But when I try to create a widget nothing shows up on the page.

Comment: Where in `page.xml` did you add that XML, and which `view.phtml` file are you referencing?

Comment: in which page.xml did you add it? You must give us more information. Normally you need to have a reference to tell in which block to add your block.

Comment: I have my own theme folder so within app/design/frontend/theme/layout/page.xml. Then the view.phtml is in app/design/frontend/theme/template/catalog/product. So in the page.xml I put it right under the "Main content area" block, and in the view.phtml i'm echoing it instead of the "media".